# ctags.exe & etags.exe return Permission denied

Tags: windows-10, ctags, exuberant-ctags, scoop-installer

I have `ctags.exe` and `etags.exe` installed via [scoop installer](https://scoop.sh/) and emacs app.
No matter how I run it, I always get a `Permission denied` error output.
Whether with CMD user or admin permissions (elevated permissions thing).

```
tomas@NUC8I7HVK D:\playground\c\milton\src
# ctags.exe .
.: Permission denied

$ C:\Users\tomas\scoop\apps\emacs\current\bin\ctags.exe .
.: Permission denied
```

This is the version used:

```
# ctags.exe -V
ctags (GNU Emacs 26.2)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed under the terms in ETAGS.README
```

I would say this is a Windows 10 thing, though I haven't found any help online.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit

You did not say the tags file failed to be generated.

"You may see messages like "Warning: cannot open source file '...' : Permission denied" while etags is building the tags file. [These warnings can be ignored](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/10au/tutorials/tutorial_ctags.html)."

[How to use ctags](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20use%20ctags&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=how%20to%20use%20ctags&sc=6-16&sk=&cvid=C511D28FDF2943619F5B0F88092BDD88)

Comment: Well, the fact is that the generated file with `tags` name is empty.
I finally installed `universal-ctags` via scoop which does work.
BTW, your first link points to a Linux tutorial, and the question is for Windows CMD. Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`ctags.exe` included on Emacs for Windows does not work for me.
I tried [universal-ctags](https://ctags.io/), which does work.

```
tomas@NUC8I7HVK D:\playground\c\milton\src
$ scoop search ctags
'extras' bucket:
    emacs (26.3) --> includes 'ctags.exe'
    universal-ctags (2020-03-12)

'main' bucket:
    ctags (5.8)

tomas@NUC8I7HVK D:\playground\c\milton\src
$ scoop search universal-ctags
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for using etags on directory trees that you might interested in.  You can run a for loop and use the -a flag to append to the TAGS file like so:

```
for /r %y in (*.c) do etags -a %y
```

The /r option in the for loop will execute the for loop in each directory of the tree.

You can also make a bat script:

```
for /r %%y in (*.c) do etags -a %%y
for /r %%y in (*.h) do etags -a %%y
```